# Why m2e retrieving architypes causes out of memory error?

Tags: out-of-memory, m2eclipse, m2e

Can you help me please.
I have Eclipse Java EE IDE Kepler
M2E: version 1.4.0

eclipse.ini:

```
...
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
1024m

-Xms256m
-Xmx512m
```

By creating a new Maven project i keep getting:
- long "Retrieving artifacts" pause
- then strange out of memory error:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Retrieving archetypes:".
GC overhead limit exceeded
```

How can it take so mutch memory?

Comment: I had a similar problem, but never found out when and why it happens.